# Android calendar - Event is created, but cant see its listed in Android default calendar

Tags: android, calendar

I am using CalendarContract.EVENTS to register an event, but not the Intent.

Now the way I am retrieving calendar id is like below -

```
String[] projection = new String[]{Calendars._ID, Calendars.NAME, Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE};
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Calendars.CONTENT_URI,projection,Calendars.IS_PRIMARY + " = 1 ",null, Calendars._ID +" ASC");
Long calId = cursor.getLong(0);
```

This calId is further used in registering an event. Though I am not getting any runtime failure, I am unable to observe an event is registered at Android Calendar.
Hence unable to establish success of my trial.
What is going wrong in my overall understanding here ?

Answer (score 0):

There is something with Calendar instance. If I try with

```
calendarInstance.set(2017,5,27,19,30)
```

It would show me event is created at Jun 27th, instead of May 27th.

One more learning in the process I had was ... ContentValues for an event must be associated with an uri of - CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI
ContentValues for event synchronization to be associated with - CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI